# How to add labels to a PDF?

Tags: pdf

I learned that you could add bookmarks to a PDF file like this:

```
pdftk file.pdf update_info_utf8 bookmarks.txt output new_file.pdf
```

where `bookmarks.txt` is a file you make. However, I can't seem to be able to do the same with the labels. I made a file with the label commands, similar to

```
PageLabelBegin
PageLabelNewIndex: 1
PageLabelStart: 1
PageLabelPrefix: cover
PageLabelNumStyle: NoNumber
PageLabelBegin
PageLabelNewIndex: 2
PageLabelStart: 1
PageLabelPrefix:  IFC-
PageLabelNumStyle: DecimalArabicNumerals
PageLabelBegin
PageLabelNewIndex: 5
PageLabelStart: 1
PageLabelNumStyle: LowercaseRomanNumerals
PageLabelBegin
PageLabelNewIndex: 6
PageLabelStart: 1
PageLabelPrefix: HEOA-1
PageLabelNumStyle: NoNumber
```

which is the same syntax `pdftk` outputs when you issue the command

```
pdftk file.pdf dump_data output data.txt
```

So my question is: how can I add labels to my PDF file?

Comment: I ended up adding lables by editing the pdf file directly with the help of qpdf. See here: [How to change internal page numbers in the meta data of a PDF](https://superuser.com/q/232553/1057390)

Answer (score 3):

This is now supported in version 3.1.0 of the Java port of pdftk. In other words, creating a file with the same syntax as a dump_data output and calling update_info like the OP tried is enough to add page labels to a PDF.